# I get the Laravel Error in my blade file which is the undefined $products?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

```
 @foreach($products as $product)
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('products.update', $product->id) }}">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="{{ $product->name }}" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="description">Description:</label>
            <textarea name="description" id="description" required>{{ $product->description }}</textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="price">Price:</label>
            <input type="number" name="price" id="price" value="{{ $product->price }}" step="0.01" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="design">Design:</label>
            <select name="design" id="design" required>
                <option value="design1" {{ $product->design === 'design1' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Design 1</option>
                <option value="design2" {{ $product->design === 'design2' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Design 2</option>
                <option value="design3" {{ $product->design === 'design3' ? 'selected' : '' }}>Design 3</option>
                <!-- Add more options as needed -->
            </select>
        </div>

        <!-- Add more fields if necessary -->

        <button type="submit">Update</button>
    </form>
```

this is my blade structure i just want to update a product data using a form but it caught an error of undefined $products. PS: Im still a newbie at laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you use $products (with a "s"). It would be easier to understand that your dealing with only one product here using the singular form. And i think you have done right on your controller and use $product instead of $products. So i guess it's only a typo error

Comment: hi thanks for your comment i have updated the format but still the same issue idk why

Comment: Does your controller provides well $products ? You can use `Log` interface to output data informations on a `storage/logs/laravel.log` file.
`Log::info("This is the products variable i'm sending to my view", $products);`
Please be careful, you may not use the $products variable like this in your controller, so you may change your variable name

Comment: @JohnMarkEntrina - Can you please share the controller function here so it will be easy to find out where is the issue either in the controller or blade?